# How to implement one non-static method for only 3 children of a class?

Tags: c#, class, structure

I have 7 classes which inherit the "Base" class :

- Base
- Class1 : Base
- Class2 : Base
- ...
- Class7 : Base

For 3 of these 7 classes, I have to add a **non-static** method (exactly the same code), but this method should **not** be visible for the others classes, and I don't know how to organize my code.

Anybody can help me ?

**Edit :**
I can't do like this :

- Base

  - Class with 'secret' method : Base
  - Class1 : Class with 'secret' method
  - Class2 : Class with 'secret' method
  - Class3 : Class with 'secret' method
  - Class4 : Base
  - Class5 : Base
  - Class6 : Base
  - Class7 : Base

Because in the non-static method, I use an attribute which is declared in the Class1, Class2 and Class3 classes (and I can't move it, it's handled by Entity Framework). Example :

```
this.var
```

Comment: You're wasting peoples time when you have special requirements but neglect to mention them.  Your question is too vague and will need a concrete example to explain what you are trying to do.  This class1, class2 stuff makes it more confusing.  I also think you are using the wrong terminology.  Do you mean property?  Attributes look like this `[Attribute]` and decorate a class

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Good explanation, but just for the sake of completeness, an attribute can decorate the class and/or it's members, properties, and methods.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I mean "property".

Answer (score 5):

Do it like so:

- Base

  - Class with 'secret' method : Base

    - Class1 : Class with 'secret' method
    - Class2 : Class with 'secret' method
    - Class3 : Class with 'secret' method
  - Class4 : Base
  - Class5 : Base
  - Class6 : Base
  - Class7 : Base

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways to reuse code than inheritance.  Inheritance should only be used when you need an "is-a" type, not simply because you don't want multiple copies of code.

Containment might be a better choice.  But, it depends on what exactly your method does.

For instance:

```
public class Contained {
    public void SpecialMethod() {}
}

public class Class1 : Base {
    private Contained _contained = new Contained();

    public override void NormalMethod() {
        // do some work
        _contained.SpecialMethod();
    }
}

public class Class2 : Base {
    private Contained _contained = new Contained();

    public override void NormalMethod() {
        // do some work
        _contained.SpecialMethod();
    }
}
```